# Setting up data for keras using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tensorflow, keras

How do I read data from a CSV file and turn into my training data and labels?

```
TRAIN_DATA = "C:\\Users\jackt\Desktop\machine_learning_coursework\MY_TRAIN.csv"
TEST_DATA = "C:\\Users\jackt\Desktop\machine_learning_coursework\MY_LABELS.csv"


train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("MY_TRAIN.csv", TRAIN_DATA)
test_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("MY_LABELS.csv", TEST_DATA)

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
```

MY output error is.

Exception: URL fetch failure on C:\Users\jackt\Desktop\machine_learning_coursework\MY_TRAIN.csv: None -- unknown url type: c

Comment: get_file is to get files from the internet, not from your local computer. You do not need to use it

Comment: what would be the correct function?

Comment: There is no correct function for "you do not need to do that step". If the files are in your local hard drive, there is no need to get them from the internet. That is what this code does.

Comment: Keras uses data in Numpy or Pandas format. So use 'numpy.loadtxt()' or 'pandas.read_csv()' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read csv file, create two empty list, append the image and labels data to respective list, convert it into numpy arrays and save it.

At the time of training, load it using scikit package and shuffle it. There are numerous tutorials for that.

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import join
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

# Read columns (multiple ways to do it)
images = train_df["images"]
labels = train_df["labels"]

train_data = []
train_label = []

for (image, label) in zip(images, labels):
    img = cv2.imread(join("train_dir", image))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # if you want to resize images to a particular shape
    img = cv2.resize(img, (160, 160), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) 

    # Append images and labels
    train_data.append(img)
    train_label.append(label)

train_data = np.array(train_data)
train_label = np.array(train_label)
train_label = to_categorical(train_label)

np.save("train_data.npy", train_data)
np.save("train_label.npy", train_label)
```